SSD1306 OLED Display Issue
I’m working on a project called “SenseBox” that includes:

CH340
ESP8266
BME680 sensor
SSD1306 OLED display

https://gitlab.com/bytewire/sensebox

The hardware implementation for the Display i got from here: http://wiki.sunfounder.cc/index.php?title=OLED-SSD1306_Module
Got the display from aliexpress: https://de.aliexpress.com/item/1005006419941940.html
The BME680 and OLED display are both connected to the ESP8266 via I2C. The sensor works great, and I’m getting data without any issues. However, the display refuses to turn on. The I2C connection seems fine, and there’s no error in the software.
I tried both I2C addresses i found mentioned online which are 0x3C and 0x3D. My test implementation looks like the following
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>
#include <Arduino.h>

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 128  // OLED display width, in pixels
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 64  // OLED display height, in pixels
#define OLED_RESET    -1   // Reset pin # (or -1 if sharing Arduino reset pin)

Adafruit_SSD1306 display(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, &Wire, OLED_RESET);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Initializing SSD1306...");

  // SSD1306 initialization
  if (!display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C)) {  // Address 0x3C for 128x64
    Serial.println(F("SSD1306 allocation failed"));
    while (true); // Don't proceed, loop forever
  }

  Serial.println("SSD1306 initialized successfully.");

  display.clearDisplay();
  display.setTextSize(1);      // Normal 1:1 pixel scale
  display.setTextColor(SSD1306_WHITE); // Draw white text
  display.setCursor(0, 0);     // Start at top-left corner
  display.println(F("Hello, World!"));
  display.display();

  Serial.println("Message displayed on SSD1306.");
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("Updating display...");
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.setCursor(0, 0);
  display.println("Testing SSD1306");
  display.display();

  delay(1000);

  display.clearDisplay();
  display.setCursor(0, 0);
  display.println("ESP8266 Debug Output");
  display.display();

  delay(1000);
}

I’ve attached the schematics for reference. Any ideas on why the display might not be working?
EDIT:
From the Datasheet: After VDD become stable, set RES# pin LOW (logic low) for at least 3us (t1) (4) and then HIGH (logic high). 
https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/SSD1306.pdf
Voltage on C14 (RST) after inserting the usb connector


The library code is a black box provided by Arduino and you are using a black box which we can't see if it does things correctly or not. We also don't know if it is supposed to work on your specific display. Without adding more info and debugging where the problem might be, we can't say what the problem might be.

Do you mean this blackbox? https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_SSD1306
I tried a I2C Scanner:
https://pastebin.com/kMU9M5m7
I2C device found at address 0x3C !
I2C device found at address 0x76 !
I2C scan complete.
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
Still nothing on the display. But the scanner found the adress. So I suspect there must be a hardware related issue, which is not obvious to me tho

AliExpress are not to be trusted when it comes to many electronic products. Neither are eBay, Amazon and several others. If the schematic links die (as they do over time), your question becomes invalid. You should embed the info into your question.

I embedded the image of the schematic, but a moderator (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/64158/marcus-m%c3%bcller) removed it

I don't see anything obviously wrong. Have you verified that the display /RESET pin is high? Are you using a socket for the display FPC?

I soldered the display directly to the board. I verified the voltage on c14 which is 3.274v. R11 is 4.7 kOhm, not as in the schematic 1k

I edited my post and posted the solution! Thanks everyone

@eikood You should post that as answer. Since the I2C was working, clearly the problem must be either in hardware like your missing power supply do it does not light up, or some custom init command missing over I2C.

Please post images with more contrast the next time, optimally black-on-white. Presumably only few of us are working in the dark and in dark mode. ;-)

I discovered the problem was due to high contact resistance at one of the solder joints on the pump charge capacitor (specifically C13/C14).
After resoldering the affected joints, everything is now working as intended. Just a heads-up if anyone else runs into similar issues!
